# Cant' compile AspectJ with IntelliJ and OpenJDK 9

Tags: intellij-idea, aspectj, java-9

We are using AspectJ 1.9.1.

We compile our code in two ways:
1. using Apache Ant 1.10.2
2. using IntelliJ 2008.2 Pro.

In IntelliJ we have been using OpenJDK 8 as the SDK, and everything including our ApspectJ aspects compile just fine and we are happy.

However, as soon as we change the SDK to OpenJDK 9 (9.0.7.1) we get the following compile error:

```
Error: Module 'eXist-db' production: org.aspectj.bridge.AbortException: can't determine superclass of missing type java.lang.Object
[Xlint:cantFindType]
```

In IntelliJ we have the AspectJ plugin installed, and the Java Compiler is set to AJC, the following checkboxes are all checked on:
1. Use '--release' option for cross-compilation (Java 9 and later)
2. Generate debug info
3. Delegate to javac

Our Module in IntelliJ has the AspectJ option set for "Post-compile weave mode".

Can someone help us to get this compiling in IntelliJ with OpenJDK 9 please?

For comparison - our Ant build works just fine with AspectJ on both OpenJDK 8 and OpenJDK 9; So we suspect some configuration issue with IntelliJ invoking the AspectJ ajc compiler.

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with a sample project to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but it seems to be a bug in the IntelliJ AspectJ plugin. I'm having a similar problem with IntelliJ AspectJ "Post-compile weave mode" and Java11. I filed a bug report with Jetbrains:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219318